# Is there any way to choose a mobile keyboard without input[type]?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I want to show different keyboards in the event an input is a date without it actually being a `<input type="date" />`.

Is this possible?

Comment: ¿In Mobile (Phonegap, etc), React Native or simply Web Navigator?

Comment: @JoelJaime Mobile browsers like chrome

Comment: Perfect, in that case, check my answer on this page Kevin

Comment: What input can you use? `input[type=text]`?

Comment: @DerekHopper Yes :)

Answer (score -1):

The answer is YES.

> **For email keyboard**

```
<input type="email" name="email" />
```

[image]

-

> **For URL**

```
<input type="url" name="url">
```

[image]

-

> **For telephone**

```
<input type="tel" name="tel">
```

[image]

-

> **Numbers**

```
<input type="number" name="number">
```

[image]

-

> **Datetime**

```
<input type="date" name="date">
```

[image]

These are the most used so far.
Greetings.

Comment: I specifically asked for a solution that wasn't that one. I can't use the `type` attribute.

Comment: ¿Why can not you use that property?
It is not possible to use another type of keyboard if you do not indicate the property, if you have any problem in the HTML or how you are generating the property you can assign it to JavaScript.

But in conclusion, if you can not use it (I do not understand why) it is not possible to change the keyboard type.